# Include the trailing space in sprintf in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, des

I'm trying to implement the `DES` cipher in Matlab.
In order to have the bits for the plain text and key, I'm doing this:

```
binInput = hex2bin(sprintf('%x',input));
```

Where `hex2bin` is a function gave to us by the professor.
This gives me the hex for the input, then the binary of it as `char` array.

I noted that when `input` has a trailing space, it is ignored, hence my algorithm stops to work because the block is not 64 bit long anymore (i get a `1x15` char vector instead of a `1x16` for example).
How can I include this trailing space? I could not find anything online or in the `help` of `sprintf`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The trailing space is preserved. You should just pad your `input` with `' '` to make it a length of 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` *does* respect all whitespace regardless of whether it's trailing, leading, or in-between.

```
sprintf('%x', 'hello')
%   68656c6c6f

sprintf('%x', 'hello ')
%   68656c6c6f20
```

If you need your input length to be a multiple of 64-bits, you'll likely want to pad your data with null bytes

```
str((end+1):(end+mod(numel(str), 8))) = '0';
```

If anything is getting truncated, it is likely an issue with the `hex2bin` function your professor gave you.

Comment: yeah It's definetly a problem with `hex2bin`, I tried another way of conversion from ascii to binary and there is no problem